# How do I make a merge sort, built for a single list, sort a "list of list" instead?

Tags: python

So, let say I have a list of lists like this:

```
[[0,9,8],[1, 7, 9],[2, 8, 9], [3, 5, 7]]
```

If I wanted to sort this by the middle number in each sublist, it would end up like this:

```
[[3, 5, 7],[2, 7, 9],[2, 8, 9],[0, 9, 8]]
```

How can I cause a merge sort that is built to sort a list like this:

[1, 2, 3, 4]

To sort a list of list and specify it to merge based on the middle number of each sublist? Is there a trick with python that will allow this to work? Only thing I have been able to find about this is using the built-in sorting function, which I do not want to do.

Below is the merge sort I am implementing. It works like this

mergeSort(list_here)

And it merges the list. However, I would like to use a trick to make python merge based on a list of the list instead with the middle index of each sublist being what is being compared.

Thanks for any guidance. Below is the merge sort:

```
def mergeSort(list_num):
    mergeSort2(list_num, 0, len(list_num)-1)


def mergeSort2(list_num, first, last):
    if first < last:
        middle = (first+last)//2
        mergeSort2(list_num, first, middle)
        mergeSort2(list_num, middle+1, last)
        merge(list_num, first, middle, last)


def merge(list_num, first, middle, last):
    L = list_num[first:middle+1]
    R = list_num[middle+1:last+1]
    L.append(sys.maxsize)
    R.append(sys.maxsize)
    i = j = 0

    for k in range(first, last+1):
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            list_num[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            list_num[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
```

Comment: It's tricky to generalize your current mergesort algorithm because of the `sys.maxsize` sentinels that you append to the `L` and `R` sublists. If you tried to sort a list of lists, or even a list of strings, you'd need to use a different sentinel value. (For that matter, your code won't work properly on a list of integers if any of those integers were >`sys.maxsize`). So if you want a general version you first need to re-write `merge` so that it doesn't need those sentinels, or has some way of creating those sentinels that's not tied to `sys.maxsize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that can accept a key function, like the built-in `sort` and related functions do.

I use `max` to create the "sentinel" value. This is rather inefficient, since `max` has to scan the whole list to find its maximum. Also, the built-in `sort` only calls the key function once for each item in the list it's sorting, whereas this code has to call it twice every time it makes a comparison.

```
def mergeSort(list_num, key=None):
    mergeSort2(list_num, 0, len(list_num)-1, key=key)

def mergeSort2(list_num, first, last, key=None):
    if first < last:
        middle = (first+last)//2
        mergeSort2(list_num, first, middle, key=key)
        mergeSort2(list_num, middle+1, last, key=key)
        merge(list_num, first, middle, last, key=key)

def merge(list_num, first, middle, last, key=None):
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x

    L = list_num[first:middle+1]
    R = list_num[middle+1:last+1]
    sentinel = max(list_num, key=key)
    L.append(sentinel)
    R.append(sentinel)
    i = j = 0

    for k in range(first, last+1):
        if key(L[i]) <= key(R[j]):
            list_num[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            list_num[k] = R[j]
            j += 1

# Test

lst = [3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 2]
print(lst)
mergeSort(lst)
print(lst)

lst = [[0, 9, 8], [1, 7, 9], [2, 8, 9], [3, 5, 7]]
print(lst)
mergeSort(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(lst)
```

**output**

```
[3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[[0, 9, 8], [1, 7, 9], [2, 8, 9], [3, 5, 7]]
[[3, 5, 7], [1, 7, 9], [2, 8, 9], [0, 9, 8]]
```

As you can see, it works, but it would be better to change your merging algorithm to eliminate the sentinels so we don't need `max`.

We can also make it more efficient by performing a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) on the data so that the key function only needs to be called once per item, but that does make the code a little more complicated, and of course it also requires more RAM to hold the transformed data.

Comment: That let me in the right direction and I appreciate your help. Although, I would point out that it does it in descending order. However, it is not a big deal, as you can simply change R and L out at the for loop in the merge function and it will correct itself.

Comment: @user7977797 No worries, but those lists look like they are sorted in ascending order to me.

Comment: Ring , I think you are actually correct. It does appear to be sorting in ascending order. Please ignore the above message.

Answer (score 0):

If did understand you right, the following code is what you want:

```
l_sorted = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

where l is your input list.

Comment: Right, but you are using the built in sort function. I am looking to use the one I have built to sort a list. How can I do it with the one I provided below (merge sort)?

Comment: Change `if L[i] &lt;= R[j]:` to `if L[i][1] &lt;= R[j][1]:`. I cant test it currently.

Comment: I attempted that and it gave me the error:

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'